# Parsing JSON object from Firebase and using key value pairs to generate content

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have set up a database with Firebase and I have populated it with JSON information. I have code, taken directly from the Firebase documentation, that takes a snapshot of my data and updates it in real time. This is great for what I need, but I also need to access the values in my JSON to generate lists of content similarly to this:

```
var JSONStuff = json info on database
for (every array in the JSON)
{
  //MAKE THINGS
}
```

I usually do this with php scripts and SQL databases, but I am using Firebase for the first time and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Here is what I have so far.

JavaScript:

```
var display = document.getElementById("resultsDisplay");
var dbRef = firebase.database().ref().child("workouts");
// Sync with Firebase in real time.
dbRef.on("value", snap =>
{
  //display.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(snap.val(), null, 3); This correctly prints my JSON.
  JSON.stringify(snap.val(), null, 3);
});

JSON.parse(dbRef) //Trying to parse the JSON and do things with it.
{
  for (var i = 0, len = dbRef.length; i < len; i++)
  {
    display.innerHTML = 'Routine: ' + dbRef.title + ' Exercises: ' + dbRef.name + '.';
  }
};
```

HTML:

```
<div id="resultsDisplay">boo</div>
```

The console gives me the "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token h in JSON" error, which I know means there are double quotes messing with my parser somewhere, but as you can see I am not using them in the function.

I am a noob and therefore probably doing something completely silly, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are trying to `JSON.parse` the database reference, not the value. You need to operate inside the `.on('value')` callback and use the `snap.val()` for your JSON, not `dbRef`.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. However, all I have achieved is to get rid of console errors, nothing else shows. I presume I am referencing key:value pairs incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you are trying to parse the database reference `dbRef` and not the data itself.

Try to do this:

```
var display = document.getElementById("resultsDisplay");
var dbRef = firebase.database().ref().child("workouts");

// Sync with Firebase in real time.
dbRef.on("value", snap => {
  var workoutsJSON = JSON.stringify(snap.val(), null, 3);

  JSON.parse(workoutsJSON) {
    for (var i = 0, len = dbRef.length; i < len; i++) {
      display.innerHTML = 'Routine: ' + dbRef.title + ' Exercises: ' + dbRef.name + '.';
    }
  };
});
```

Just to give you an idea.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, If I implement your code the console does not show any errors, but at the same time the div does not get updated and nothing is displayed. I presume this is an issue with how I am referencing the key:value pairs in my database.

Comment: UPDATE: The issue is not with referencing the key:value pairs. I converted my JSON into a JS variable and parsed through it and was then able to print individual values, but not loop through them (so I must be doing something wrong with the for loop as well). I then tried to print the same information from the server using your code, it returned 'undefined' and no console errors.

Comment: @Brian Is it possible to create a plunkr? then I will solve to your needs within a few minutes.

Comment: here is the plunk: https://plnkr.co/edit/52vgPr8CufhefW5LFBwL?p=preview

Comment: Do you really need the JSON? I think you just want to display your firebase's data. I've forked your plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/gMZbEkyPGsgT0LDmiUZD     if you want to display them in a for loop you will need to append them to the DOM instead of usiing the `innerHTML` property.

Comment: @Orlandtser, thank you so much your help has been invaluable. Unfortunatley yeah, I need the JSON: I need to be able to create list vies dynamically with it, I need the user to be able to modify it, and I need to feed the values to a recursive timer that will display them while cycling through the data.